# SQL update table refers to itself

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table `ProfileText` which contains four columns: `Id, Text, State, PreviousText`.

`State` is an enum with the following states: `released, draft`.

`PreviousText` is a reference to another `ProfileText`.

Whenever a new `ProfileText` is created, the previous `ProfileText` is set as `PreviousText`. The `State` does not matter. This creates a kind of "timeline" of released and drafted texts. Now I want to modify `PreviousText`. The "timeline" should only contain entries with `State = released`.

Example old: A(released) -> B(draft) -> C(released) -> null

Example new: A(released) -> C(released) -> null

How can I make this update table in SQL?

Comment: Do you want to keep a history of the changed row values?  Or do you just want to keep one row and store the previous `ProfileText` value in `PreviousText`?  If it's the latter, then just a simple `UPDATE` statement will do.  If it's the former, then you need to some kind of `UPDATE / INSERT ` transaction.

Comment: Your goal is very unclear. can you try to try to restate it Do you want to delete records which are (PreviousText) that and are not released?  .

Comment: I do not want to delete anything in the table. I just want to exchange all `PreviousText` with `State =  draft` for previous/earlier with `State = released`. `PreviousText` is something like a shortcut to the previous element with `State = released`.

Comment: which sql version?

Comment: PostgreSQL version 9.3

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you should be able to accomplish this with an update that makes use of a recursive CTE (common table expression):

```
with recursive timeline as (
    select * from ProfileText where State = 'released'
  union
    select a.Id, a.Text, a.State, b.PreviousText
    from timeline as a
      join ProfileText as b on b.Id = a.PreviousText
    where b.State <> 'released'
)
update ProfileText as a set PreviousText = b.PreviousText
from timeline as b
  left join ProfileText as c on c.Id = b.PreviousText
where a.Id = b.Id and
      (b.PreviousText is null or c.State = 'released'
        and a.PreviousText <> b.PreviousText);
```

What this does is it selects all "released" records in the non-recursive part of the CTE regardless of the state of previous records they may be referencing, then for any that reference previous records which are not released, it yields additional records containing the original values of the released entry with the reference to the previous entry's previous entry, continuing until it reaches a released record or a null reference.

Then all it has to do is update all entries in the table that are in the newly constructed timeline and either have a null entry in the timeline (necessary for when the oldest released entry is not the oldest entry) or have an entry referencing a previous "released" record that is not reflected in the old timeline.